# CoreData many to many relationship Best practices

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, many-to-many, entity-relationship

give the structure:

#### Person

- field1
- ...
- fieldn
- >>itemsTaken(inverse: takenFrom)

#### Item

- field1
- ...
- fieldn
- >> takenFrom(inverse: itemsTaken)

Person.itemsTaken <<------>>Items.takenFrom

the scenario is that I have a list of Persons and a list of Items

now I would to show within the Person Detail View the items he taken (this is simply solved), and to show on the Item detail View the complete list of persons and select a subset of person that taken that item.

the problem is the 2nd view where I would to add/remove from the orderedset "takenFrom" a person.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let mo = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject

    if var x: NSMutableOrderedSet = mo.valueForKey("itemsTaken") as? NSMutableOrderedSet {
        x.addObject(detailItem)
        mo.setValue(x, forKey: "itemsTaken")
    }
    if var x: NSMutableOrderedSet = detailItem.valueForKey("takenFrom") as? NSMutableOrderedSet {
        x.addObject(mo)
        detailItem.setValue(x, forKey: "takenFrom")
    }
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).saveContext()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let mo = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject


    if var x: NSMutableOrderedSet = mo.valueForKey("itemsTaken") as? NSMutableOrderedSet {
        x.removeObject(detailItem)
        mo.setValue(x, forKey: "itemsTaken")
    }
    if var x: NSMutableOrderedSet = detailItem.valueForKey("takenFrom") as? NSMutableOrderedSet {
        x.removeObject(mo)
        detailItem.setValue(x, forKey: "takenFrom")
    }

    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).saveContext()


}
```

that works but when I restarted the app all references for relationship are lost
but I'm not sure I'm proceeding in the correct way.

before this approach I had 2 more entities in order to have for each entity a one 2 many relationships. I'm looking for a cleaner solution

do you have any suggestion or question?

just a clarification. the target is to add/remove references from person.itemsTaken and/or Item.takenFRom
I would to avoid to delete Person. can I remove only the reference within the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cleaner solution": first step would be to make your code more readable. Why call a variable `mo` or `x` if the object is better described as a `person` or as `itemsTaken`? An additional strategy to make your code more readable is to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Second, it seems that you are adding the relationship twice (once for each side). I don't think this is necessary.

Third, you might want to check if your mutable ordered set is extracted the way you expect. I think it might be advisable to use the mutable accessor instead:

```
var itemsTaken = person.mutableSetValueForKey("itemsTaken")
```

Not sure if you still have to cast or do other things in order to keep the ordering in the ordered set. In my experience, the ordered set never really worked reliably even in Objective-C, so you might just want to keep an additional attribute for the ordering and change the model to use a simple many-to-many relationship.

Comment: hi Mundi, 1. you have right about the readable code. it was only a first test. 2. after that I tried without the second add for the inverse relationship but it didn't solved the problem. 3. this  works and also the inverse relationship was populated correctly. Now it will be great to understand why the valueForKey + casting failed. I use this way as alternative to have a managedObject that maps Entity. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sure. If you a method returns a non-mutable set, you can cast as much as you want, the pointer will still point to the non-mutable object. (Remember, these are just pointers.) The casting will simply silence the compiler. Instead, to get a mutable object, you would have to use a factory method that produces a mutable object.

Comment: In swift CoreData: How would you create the inverse relation say many-many?

Comment: - update: In swift CoreData: How would you create the inverse relation say to-many, or is inverse relation automatically stablished after you set the relation to a particular object?

Comment: @Allan automatically.